# ffmpeg command for php not working on live server

Tags: php, video, ffmpeg, upload, thumbnails

I am generating thumbnail from video while uploading  and I have installed ffmpeg on local but in live server ffmpeg is not installed and  hosting provider asking extra charges  to install  it, so  i have kept ffmpeg directory  which i copied from local  machine and placed to live server and provided live server path and try to call script but it is not generating thumbnail

```
$ffmpeg = 'https://example.com/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe';
        $video_temp_path = $_FILES['upload_file']['tmp_name']; 
        $video_title = $_FILES['upload_video']['name'];


        $image = 'upload/' . $video_title . uniqid().'.jpg';
//time to take screenshot at
        $interval = 5;
//screenshot size
        $size = '320x240';
//ffmpeg command
       $command = $ffmpeg.' -i '.$video_temp_path.' -deinterlace -an -ss '.$interval.' -f mjpeg -t 1 -r 1 -y -s '.$size.' '.$image.' 2>&1';

       exec($command, $array);
```

Comment: Not sure if it will work - but your path will definitely not work.  It would need to be the local path and not look as though it's running an executable over the web!

Comment: I forgot to mention path i will update my question

Comment: I meant the path `$ffmpeg`

Comment: $ffmpeg = 'https://example.com/public_html/ffmpeg/bin/ffmpeg.exe';

Comment: ffmpeg directory placed in public_html folder in live server

Comment: I doubt if you can run an executable with a URL path, it will need to be a local file path.

Comment: ok,can you please tell me alternate way to to generate thumbnail from video using php

Comment: godaddy not provide ffmpeg

Comment: You don't need godaddy to provide ffmpeg. Just [download](https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/) it, put it on server, and execute.

Answer (score 0):

after upload ffmpeg on live server restart server first then it's work